# JavaScript how to test if one IPv6 address is larger than another?

Tags: javascript

Given two IPv6 addresses in string format i.e. "2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8328" and "2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329"

how can I test if one is larger than the other? IPv4 was easy, convert into an integer value and compare, but IPv6 numbers are so large this becomes unfeasable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `:` and do a hexa compare for the entire string.

```
var first = "2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8328".replace(/:/g, "");
var second = "2001:0db8:0000:0000:0000:ff00:0042:8329".replace(/:/g, "");

// compare
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the address by ":" transform individually each term as **hexadecimal** value.

Compare the final result of each string.

```
function toHex(str) {
    var hex = '';
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
        hex += ''+str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third party library, there's [ip-address](https://github.com/beaugunderson/ip-address).